# Combine filter and map in Xtend collections

Tags: xtend

Given some iterable variable `v` and a type `T` I often find myself writing code such as

`v.filter[it instanceof T].map[it as T]`

Does there exist some helper which does the same functionality in a single step?

Answer (score 8):

You may want to use `v.filter(T)` (or the legacy syntax `v.filter(typeof(T))`) which is Xtend's syntax for the Java equivalent `v.filter(T.class)`.